# Cannot link realsense library on c++ on qt creator

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, qt-creator, realsense

I am trying basic C++ programs with Intel Realsense sdk2 with [librealsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/examples) library on Qt Creator. My .pro file looks like the following

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/magbot/opencv-3.4.8/build/include
LIBS += -L/home/magbot/opencv-3.4.8/build/lib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgcodecs \

LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lrealsense2 \

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

OpenCV libraries compile fine but the realsense library does not link. I get this error 
**error: cannot find -lrealsense2** . The folder /usr/lib/x86.... contains the file librealsense2.so [image] but its in red. Please help...where am I doing it wrong

Comment: How have you installed/compiled realsense?

Comment: Notice how `librealsense2.so` is red, while other are white or blue. That (most probably) means most probably it is a symbolic link that points to a nonexistent file. Please post the output of `ls -lah /usr/lib/x86...../librealsense*`. Or you could just remove the symbolic link and link it to `libreadlsense2.so.2.30` by hand and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is some error with your installation. I checked with Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Both installation looks fine installed via package manager.

You should try reinstalling it. If you want to install it with package manager(apt-get) follow [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md)

If you are installing from source code that follow [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation.md)

As mention in comment by [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk), you can also try to remove dead symbolic link and then create new one.

```
rm /usr/lib/x86.../librealsense2.so
ln -s /usr/lib/x86.../librealsense2.so.2.30 /usr/lib/x86.../librealsense2.so
```